# Why does reconnecting to an Oracle database via dbExpress cause an access violation?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, oracle11g, dbexpress

I have a Delphi 2006 application running on Windows 7 that connects to an Oracle database via dbExpress using an Oracle 11 client install. After the first connect, I can query data and everything works as expected. However, when I disconnect and then re-connect, I get the following error:

```
Exception EAccessViolation in module orageneric11.dll at 00450EB5. 
Access violation at address 048A0EB5 in module 'orageneric11.dll'.
Read of address 00000038
```

The same application is running fine on Windows XP using an Oracle 10 client install (unfortunately, I don't have a test-setup with XP + Oracle 11 or Windows 7 + Oracle 10).

I have reduced the problem to the following:

```
program OracleReconnectTest; 

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 

uses
  SysUtils,
  SqlExpr; 

var
  connection: TSQLConnection;

begin
  connection := TSQLConnection.Create( nil );
  connection.DriverName := 'Oracle';
  connection.LibraryName := 'dbxora30.dll';
  connection.VendorLib := 'oci.dll';
  connection.GetDriverFunc := 'getSQLDriverORACLE';
  connection.LoginPrompt := False;
  connection.Params.Text :=
    'DATABASE=TheDatabase' + #$D#$A +
    'USER_NAME=TheUser' + #$D#$A +
    'PASSWORD=ThePassword' + #$D#$A +
    'DECIMAL SEPARATOR=,'; 

  connection.Connected := True; 

  Writeln( 'Connected once, press ENTER to disconnect and reconnect' );
  Readln; 

  connection.Connected := False;
  connection.Connected := True; // <- access violation on Windows 7 + Oracle 11

  Writeln( 'Reconnected, press ENTER to exit' );
  Readln;
end.
```

I suppose this rules out a problem with my application code. I have stepped through the dbExpress code that comes with Delphi, but haven't encountered anything that looks wrong or would explain this.

So I haven't been able to find anything that indicates this to be a bug in either dbExpress or the Oracle driver. Hence I wouldn't know whether to file a bug against with Embarcadero and/or Oracle.

The version of `orageneric11.dll` is `11.2.0.1`, and `dbxora30.dll` is version `10.0.2151.25345`.

Because it has caused problems when multiple client versions were installed in parallel, the machine in question only has the 11 client. Using Process Explorer, I have verified that only DLLs from the 11 client are used.

Has anybody else encountered this issue and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you connect/disconnect multiple times at Design Time?
Unfortunately I get an exception "Uknown driver: Oracle" when copy/paste your example above and haven't time to investigate. But i can connection/disconnect multiple times at Design time and I'm connecting to an Oracle 11g DB with an 11 client.  My Dlls are the same version as yours

Comment: ok.  Added Data.DBXOracle to the uses clause and it ran correctly.  I managed to reconnect succesfully.  Do you only have the 11 client installed?  We have add issues when we were running 9 client so the path order was important

Comment: @Jason There is only the 11 client installed (clarified that in my question). I will check whether I can re-connect at design time when I get to the office.

Comment: @Jason Same access violation when connecting and disconnecting at design time.

Comment: sorry. Not sure then.  What version of Delphi are you using?  Mine was with XE2 and Delphi 6.  Both work fine. Maybe reinstall the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have a "nice and sweet" solution that would fix it, but there are some options you may consider:

a) Change the used driver and try your luck accessing the database via ODBC after setting up an ODBC DSN on the client for the specified database. An Open Source driver can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dbexpress/

b) Buy a new version of Delphi. That may be a real pain, I know. It'll cost money and time (more if 3rd party components are involved), but sometimes it's just not the best idea to use products that are more than a decade old. The company and the intellectual property behind Delphi have since then been transformed / sold several times to different companies. There is absolutely no chance to get official support for this legacy product.

c) (really ugly, but may have its chance): Build up a pooling mechanism to prevent ever closing the connection. Sounds really ridiculous, doesn't it?

Comment: I did in fact go with option c). Not pretty, but it works. a) was a no-go because the effort of maintaining ODBC data sources on every client and server machine was out of the question. And so was  spending money on a newer version of Delphi for option b).

Comment: What do you do when you have to close the connection? (e.g. user changes password that the connection is using)  If you free and create a new connection object do you still get the same AV error?